# Cannot get hover and select on UI buttons to work in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, button, menu, textmeshpro

I'm having trouble making a very simple main menu. I've looked up many tutorials and other Stack Overflow questions, but many are pretty old and Unity updates regularly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eJA4.png)

I've tried to eliminate every other component in the scene as to not obstruct anything else. There is no other object than the button itself (inside a canvas) and the camera. The camera is tagged as MainCamera. Input handling in the player settings is marked as 'both' for Old and New input system. Somehow the button will just not react.

Am I missing something incredibly obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was missing an EventSystem.

I had tried an EventSystem before which gave me errors. That was not something I put in myself but was something Unity generated and put in for me. I had to download a Main Menu asset and copy their Event System and now it works.

Comment: guessing you used the new input, and the old event system you had was for old input..

Comment: `EventSystem` has an `InputModule` component attached .. depending on which input system you use you have to also use the according `InputModule` .. sounds like yours was the wrong one ;)